# puma-dev do not work with error message rbenv: puma: command not found

Tags: rbenv, puma-dev

When try to open site get error message `unexpected exit:`

Check dev logs `tail -f log/development.log`:

```
rbenv: puma: command not found

The `puma' command exists in these Ruby versions:
2.4.0
```

While search for answer found that the most common problem was that there is no line `gem 'puma'` in Gemfile. But in my case already have this line.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that helped:
`gem install puma`